# I am getting segment fault error in this function. Can someone tell why?

Tags: c

I am getting segment fault error in this function. Can someone tell why?

```c
/* Looks for an addition symbol "+" surrounded by two numbers, e.g. "5+6"
   and, if found, adds the two numbers and replaces the addition subexpression 
   with the result ("(5+6)*8" becomes "(11)*8")--remember, you don't have
   to worry about associativity! */
```

```c
if (buffer[i] == '+') {
    for (startOffset = i;
         startOffset - 1 >= 0 && isNumeric(buffer[startOffset - 1]);
         --startOffset)
        ; // empty loop body
    if (startOffset == i) // For further processing
        continue;

    for (remainderOffset = i;
         remainderOffset + 1 < bufferlen && isNumeric(buffer[remainderOffset + 1]);
         ++remainderOffset)
        ; // empty loop body
    if (remainderOffset == i)
        continue;

    strncpy(operand, &buffer[startOffset], i - startOffset);
    operand[i - startOffset] = '\0';
    string2int(value1, operand);

    strncpy(operand, &buffer[remainderOffset], remainderOffset - i);
    operand[remainderOffset - i] = '\0';
    string2int(value2, operand);

    sum = value1 + value2;
    sprint(operand, "%d", sum);

    operlength = strlen(operand);
    strncpy(&buffer[startOffset], operand, operlength);
    strcpy(&buffer[operlength], &buffer[remainderOffset + 1]);

    bufferlen = bufferlen - (remainderOffset - startOffset + 1) + operlength;
}
```

Comment: `strncpy(operand, &buffer[startOffset], i-startOffset);` Looks like it might be ill-formed - did you mean to do `strncpy(operand, &buffer[startOffset], operand[i-startOffset]);`?

Comment: This also appears in error: `for(startOffset = i; startOffset -1 >=0 && isNumeric(buffer[startOffset-1]); ` Your `for` loop ends with the `;` at the end of the line and assures that `StartOffset` is `-1` for the rest of your function (since you start with `i=0` in the `for` loop at the top.

Comment: Please provide a [example], the input you give, the expected output, and the output you got. Did you try to debug? On which line is the error thrown?

Comment: valgrind is a tool designed to answer these type of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your program with the debugger flag in gdb like this cc -g "program name". If you have command line arguments, for the program execute gdb --args progname arg2 ...

It will load your program into a CLI utility which has the lines numbered. Type in 'break 32' for example and this will monitor variables on that line. At any rate, once you've compiled it with the debugger symbols and loaded it, type 'run' to start the program. If no break points are set or anything else funky, it will trigger the SEGV and tell you exactly which line of code triggered it. Run the debugger at least 3 times to make sure the segv fault is being triggered by the same line of code. Then check your memory bounds(is your array index outside of the allocated address space? You were tresspassing... Try inserting a printf line which prints off the array addresses and offset you are using to be sure your bounds aren't getting skewed; a side note, int conjunction with the gdb debugger using the breakpoint and typing 'step' on the CLI each time to step through each step, you can also at each step in your execution type in 'info locals' which will tell you the variables values in the stack space, i.e. your index variable value at each step. As an alternative to manually inserting printf lines) I am not a professional expert. It looks like continue on the 9th line is moot. Good luck!